# Blink the iPhone LED Flash with Serial Data - iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, serial-port, uart

Would it be possible to set the iPhone LED flash control line as a UART TX line in order to optically transmit serial data? If so, is there a way to do it through Xamarin? Maybe this?

https://developer.xamarin.com/api/type/System.IO.Ports.SerialPort/

Answer (score 0):

I highly doubt it.  First, you don't have any control over the latency of the flash - different devices under different loads may be able to toggle it quicker than others.  And I don't think you could toggle the flash fast enough for a reasonable data transfer rate.  You might be able to get this working in a test environment with a specific hardware setup, but I don't think it would be of any practical use.

Comment: I would suspect it would be the same general idea of flashing the screen like the ElectricImp does with BlinkUp. https://electricimp.com/docs/gettingstarted/blinkup/

Comment: Nothing stops you to do something similar to Blinkup, but forget about any language/platform to help you with that, you should create a way to sync clocks, test the speed and so on, not extremely difficult, but a bit laborious. Also the speed would be very slow, 5-10 bits per second at max, but depending what you want to achieve can be enough.